# Change or animate height to css default in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a responsive website with different height setting for a header bar.
In my javascript at some point, I change this value to a fixed size :

```
$('#header').animate({marginTop: 0, height:80});
```

But at another point in my code, I would like this to revert to the original state.
How can I animate it back to the default behavior?
In other words, animating the remove inline css...

I tried

```
$('#header').animate({marginTop: 20, height:'inherit'});
```

but this doesn't work.

The original css is this :

```
#header { margin-top:20px; width:100%; height: 80px; background-color: #000; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 960px) 
{   
#header{height:100px;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) 
{
#header{height:auto; padding-bottom: 1px;}
}
```

### Failed solution 1:

---

storing the height value:
This cannot be done because a lot of users are resizing their window between the moment where the value would be stored and the moment of restoring the stored value..

### Failed solution 2:

---

animating to 'nothing', juste an empty string, fails, Jquery interprets this as 0 and animates the height to zero pixels.

Comment: used to this $('#header').animate({marginTop: 0, height:"80px"});

Answer (score 0):

You could use like this:

```
var original = $('#header').css('height');//gets original height

$('#header').animate({marginTop: 0, height:80});
```

Then revert use this:

```
$('#header').animate({marginTop: 0, height:original});
```

Comment: Thanks, but This cannot be applied here, I added why in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have HTML like below

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="info">
           My info
    </div>
</div>
```

You can do something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".item").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find('.info').stop().css('marginTop', '0');
    }).mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find('.info').animate({ marginTop: '-50px', opacity: 0.5 }, 1000);
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kX7b6/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to store the original value somewhere.  I recommend this -

```
$('#header').data('height', $(this).height()).animate({marginTop: 0, height:80});
```

Then when you are ready to revert -

```
var oldHeight = $('#header').data('height');
$('#header').animate({marginTop: 20, height: oldHeight });
```

**EDIT** --

Do you have any other inline styles for the div?

If not, you can simply use `removeAttr` and remove the `style` property.

Answer (score 0):

Try without height value or leave there just empty value height: ' '

Comment: And what about to change .animation on .css ?

Comment: This does work, but without animation, I'm using this as a fallback at the moment